# Is it bad to have \ref before you have \label and if so what to do about it?

Tags: labels

Overleaf issues a lot of warnings about having   \ref before I have \label  and idk  if I should do anything about it.

Comment: There's no problem about that. In the second compilation pass LaTeX will sort things out and the `\ref`s will point to the correct `\label`s, wherever they are. What is the exact warning message that Overleaf shows?

Comment: There should be no TeXnical reason against this and I have never seen a warning issued by (La)TeX about this. Can you show us a short code example that reproduces such a warning by Overleaf (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) as well as the exact message Overleaf shows. It could be a stylistic issue, but https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38236 suggests there is definitely no consensus that mentioning (`\ref`ing) a float before it appears (`\label`) is bad.

Answer (score 2):

On the first compilation you will get warnings about undefined labels whether or not the `\label` is before the `\ref`. On later runs the cross references will resolve and the warnings will go.

This is assuming of course that there is not an error in the markup and the `\ref`  does refer to a valid `\label`.